# Atmosphere On message Throwing message multiple times on single push

Tags: atmosphere

Hi i am learning Atmosphere framework and new to it, please help me out to fix issue that when i am pushing message through 
`socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({author:"user1", message: "hello"}));` 
but on server side i could see ***{"author":"user1","message":"hello"}, 4 times for single push.

****clientside***

```
mode.controller('pingController',['$scope','atmosphereService','$cookies',function($scope,atmosphereService,$cookies){

        $scope.model = {
            transport: 'websocket',
            messages: []
        };

        var socket;
        user=angular.fromJson($cookies.get('user_details_object'))['user_name'];
        pingUrl='/chat/'+user;
        request = {
            url:pingUrl ,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            logLevel: 'debug',
            transport: 'websocket',
            trackMessageLength: true,
            reconnectInterval: 5000,
            enableXDR: true,
            timeout: 60000
        };

        request.onOpen = function(response){
            $scope.model.transport = response.transport;
            $scope.model.connected = true;
            $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere connected using ' + response.transport;
        };

        /*request.onClientTimeout = function(response){
            $scope.model.content = 'Client closed the connection after a timeout. Reconnecting in ' + request.reconnectInterval;
            $scope.model.connected = false;
            socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({ author: "author", message: 'is inactive and closed the connection. Will reconnect in ' + request.reconnectInterval }));
            setTimeout(function(){
                socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);
            }, request.reconnectInterval);
        };*/

        request.onReopen = function(response){
            $scope.model.connected = true;
            $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere re-connected using ' + response.transport;
        };

        //For demonstration of how you can customize the fallbackTransport using the onTransportFailure function
        request.onTransportFailure = function(errorMsg, request){
            atmosphere.util.info(errorMsg);
            request.fallbackTransport = 'websocket';
            $scope.model.header = 'Atmosphere Chat. Default transport is WebSocket, fallback is ' + request.fallbackTransport;
        };

        request.onMessage = function(response){

            var responseText = response.responseBody;
            console.log("###########",responseText);
            try{
                //var message = atmosphere.util.parseJSON(responseText);
                var message = atmosphere.util.parseJSON(responseText);
                console.log("#$$$$$##",message);
                var date = typeof(message.time) === 'string' ? parseInt(message.time) : message.time;
                                $scope.model.messages.push({author: message.ping});

            }catch(e){
                console.error("Error parsing JSON: ", responseText);
                throw e;
            }
        };

        /*request.onClose = function(response){
            $scope.model.connected = false;
            $scope.model.content = 'Server closed the connection after a timeout';
            socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({ author: $scope.model.name, message: 'disconnecting' }));
        };*/

        request.onError = function(response){
            $scope.model.content = "Sorry, but there's some problem with your socket or the server is down";
            $scope.model.logged = false;
        };

        request.onReconnect = function(request, response){
            $scope.model.content = 'Connection lost. Trying to reconnect ' + request.reconnectInterval;
            $scope.model.connected = false;
        };

        socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);

        $scope.ping=function(name){
            console.log("=="+name);
            request = {
                url:'/chat/'+name ,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                logLevel: 'debug',
                transport: 'websocket',
                trackMessageLength: true,
                reconnectInterval: 5000,
                enableXDR: true,
                timeout: 60000
            };
            socket.push(atmosphere.util.stringifyJSON({author:"user1", message: "hello"}));
        }



    }]);
```

****serverside****

```
package resource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache;
import org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereSession;
import org.atmosphere.handler.OnMessage;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor;
import org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor;

@Path("/")
@AtmosphereHandlerService(path = "/chat/{user}",
        broadcasterCache = UUIDBroadcasterCache.class,
        interceptors = {AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class,
                BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor.class,
                TrackMessageSizeInterceptor.class,
                HeartbeatInterceptor.class
        })
public class NotificationResource extends OnMessage<String>{



    List<AtmosphereResource>  resourceList= new ArrayList<AtmosphereResource>();

    @Override
    public void onMessage(AtmosphereResponse response, String message)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("***"+message);

    }


}
```

output:

```
***{"author":"user1","message":"hello"}
***{"author":"user1","message":"hello"}
***{"author":"user1","message":"hello"}
***{"author":"user1","message":"hello"}
```

please help me out to fix this, i need one message, single click of push

Comment: Hello, I have actually the exact same problem. Did you find a solution since that time ?